# regex that can handle horribly misspelled words

Tags: c#, regex

Is there a way to create a regex will insure that five out of eight characters are present in order in a given character range (like 20 chars for example)?

I am dealing with horrible OCR/scanning, and I can stand the false positives.

Is there a way to do this?

**Update:** I want to match for example "mshpeln" as `misspelling`. I do not want to do OCR. The OCR job has been done, but is has been done poorly (i.e. it originally said `misspelling`, but the OCR'd copy reads "mshpeln"). I do not know what the text that I will have to match against will be (i.e. I do not know that it is "mshpeln" it could be "mispel" or any number of other combinations).

I am not trying to use this as a spell checker, but merely find the end of a capture group. As an aside, I am currently having trouble getting the all.css file, so commenting is impossible temporarily.

Comment: Can you define more strict rules what do you expect on input and output? That said, if useful method of this nature (regex-based) really existed and improved OCR recognition, I am sure that OCR folks would have jumped on it and used it across all OCR software by now.

Comment: If you already know which characters are going to be in the word processed with OCR/scanning, there is something to do, but I don't think it'd be relevant to use OCR in that case.

Comment: @Frederik.L It seems Soandos will run whole dictionary to 'guess' the word with whatever he can read in each word.

Comment: This does not sound to me like a job for regexes.

Comment: @Cyclone Regular expressions are best at handling well defined grammars and not needing to count. This question defies both.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your question? Are you only looking to find mispelling in your string, or how many different dictionary words are you looking for to try and match?

Comment: @Patashu I only want to look for one at a time (i.e. I only want to match a piece of text with one word (in the above example, misspelling). If it matches misspelling, perfect, if not, give up.

Comment: @soandos Perfect, that makes it pretty easy (see my answer).

Comment: @soandos Maybe the "Regex" could be removed from the question and instead just focus on the main problem (or maybe make it a suggestion instead of a requirement). That might spawn more answers that would solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need not regex, but database with all valid words and creative usage of functions like [`soundex()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) and/or [`levenshtein()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

You can do this: create table with all valid words (*dictionary*), populate it with columns like `word` and `snd` (computed as `soundex(word)`), create indexes for both `word` and `snd` columns.
For example, for word `mispeling` you would fill `snd` as `M214`. If you use SQLite, it has `soundex()` [implemented by default](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

Now, when you get new bad word, compute `soundex()` for it and look it up in your indexed table. For example, for word `mshpeln` it would be `soundex('mshpeln')` = `M214`. There you go, this way you can get back correct word.

But this would not look anything like regex - sorry.

Comment: I do not want to use levenshtein distance, as a distance of less than x does not mean that it has all the letters that I care about (the range is going to be large, and the distance is expected to be large (~10 or so)). I cannot create a dictionary of all the possibilities as there are too many (trillions)

Comment: Your best bet, then, is to map to the "closest" valid word - how that is precisely defined is up to you, ultimately. Try to inject rules about common OCR messups, like rn == m and others.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think that a project like this would be better for an actual human to do, not a computer.  If the project is to large for 1 or 2 people to do easily, you might want to look into something like Amazon's Mechanical Turk where you can outsource to work for pennies per solution.

Comment: That is not really an acceptable solution. I need something can work at scale, and it seems to be a rather defined problem (even if it is not suitable for regex)

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with a regex, but it can be done with a custom algorithm.

For example, to find words that are like 'misspelling' in your body of text:

1) Preprocess. Create a `Set` (in the mathematical sense, collection of guaranteed to be unique elements) with all of the unique letters that are in misspelling - `{e, i, g, l, m, n, p, s}`

2) Split the body of text into words.

3) For each word, create a `Set` with all of its unique letters. Then, perform the operation of set intersection on this set and the set of the word you are matching against - this will get you letters that are contained by both sets. If this set has 5 or more characters left in it, you have a possible match here.

If the OCR can add in erroneous spaces, then consider two words at a time instead of single words. And etc based on what your requirements are.

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the ordering? gnillepsssim is clearly not a match for example

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution for this problem, in fact, here's exactly the opposite.

Correcting OCR errors is not programmaticaly possible for two reasons:

1. You cannot quantify the error that was made by the OCR algorithm as it can goes between 0 and 100%
2. To apply a correction, you need to know what the maximum error could be in order to set an acceptable level.

Let *nello world* be the first guess of "hello world", which is quite similar. Then, with another font that is written in "painful" yellow or something, a second guess is *noiio verio* for the same expression. How should a computer know that this word would have been similar if it was better recognized?

Otherwise, given a predetermined error, mvp's solution seems to be the best in my opinion.

---

UPDATE:

After digging a little, I found a reference that may be relevant: [String similarity measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aString_similarity_measures)

Comment: I am not trying to correct the OCR. Instead, I am trying to determine if some string is the terminator of a field. I have determined the error rates that I am comfortable with, I just don't have a way to apply that.

Comment: @soandos you could use the Levenshtein distance on the field terminator candidates and the actual field terminator word. See which word has the lowest distance _or_ which field is under a certain boundary.

Comment: @soandos You may take a look at the reference I found. There's some heavy algorithm to implement, but it shows the pros and cons of each strategies.